# Separable PDE General solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Help to find the general solution for a separable PDE in the form:
$$u_{tt} = c^2  u_{xx}$$
Conditions:
$$u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0 $$
$$u(x,0) = f(x)$$
Initial derrivative:
$$u_t(x,0) = g(x)$$

I was given the following solution:
$$G_n(x)T_n(t) = u(x,t)$$

where $$G_{n}(x) = \sin (\sqrt k x)$$
$$k=(n\pi)^2$$

and
$$T_n(t)=B_n \cos(cn\pi t)+B_n^* \cos(cn\pi t)$$
but I don't know how to find $$B_n$$ and $$B_n^*$$

Please help I need this for my final!

Comment: This is just an application of Fourier series.

Comment: so $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n\geq0}G_n(x) T_n(t)=\sum_{n\geq0} \sin\cdots(a_n\cos\cdots+b_n\sin\cdots)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$$
Search for particular solutions on the form $u=X(x)T(t)$

$XT''=c^2X''T\quad;\quad \frac{T''}{T}=c^2\frac{X''}{X}=-\nu^2=$constant.

Sign $-$ in order to get sinusoidal functions and comply to the conditions $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$.

$X(x)=\sin(\nu x)=\sin(n\pi\frac{x}{L})\quad$ with $\quad\nu=n\pi\frac{1}{L}\quad$ which satisfies the condition.

$T(t)=\sin(\frac{\nu}{c}t)\quad$ and $\quad T(t)=\cos(\frac{\nu}{c}t)$

General solution complying with the condition $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ :
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{\forall n} \sin\left(n\pi\frac{x}{L}\right)\left(a_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{cL}t)+b_n\cos(\frac{n\pi}{cL}t)\right) \tag 1$$

Condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$$u(x,0)=\sum_{\forall n} b_n\sin\left(n\pi\frac{x}{L}\right)=f(x)$$
The Fourier series of $f(x)$ on $0<x<L$ gives the values of $b_n$.
$$b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \sin\left(n\pi\frac{x}{L}\right)dx$$

Condition $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ :

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{\forall n} \frac{n\pi}{cL}a_n\sin\left(n\pi\frac{x}{L}\right) =g(x)$$

The Fourier series of $g(x)$ on $0<x<L$ gives the values of $a_n$.
$$\frac{n\pi}{cL}a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L g(x) \sin\left(n\pi\frac{x}{L}\right)dx$$

With the $a_n$ and $b_n$ found, the above equation $(1)$ is solution of the PDE and satisfies all the specified conditions.